# a method to do bit-operation in C

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to define a structure that can allow to set a byte value directly, and also allow to manipulate the bits of the byte without using function like bit_set(), bit_clear() etc,.
Here's my definition

```
typedef union FLAG_WORK {
    volatile unsigned char BYTE;
    struct {
        volatile unsigned char bit0:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit1:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit2:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit3:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit4:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit5:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit6:1;
        volatile unsigned char bit7:1;
    }BIT;
}FLAG8;
```

and a sample code

```
int main()
{
    FLAG8 i;
    i.BYTE=(unsigned char)0; // initial the value of i.BYTE
    i.BIT.bit0 = 1; // set bit0 of i.BYTE
    i.BIT.bit1 = 1;
    cout << (int)i.BYTE << endl;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I just wonder how to modify the structure allowing me to assign value to "i" in above code directly?
any suggestion?

Comment: If you wanna use the union, why would you be able to do that? What would be the rationale?

Comment: If you have another `union FLAG_WORK` you can assign it to `i`, why not just assign to `i.BYTE` if you're looking to set the BYTE value?

Comment: It is a nice method to declare a 1 byte flag register, thanks and +1 for that!! :-)

Comment: It tends to work but you cannot expect the compiler to support the use of unions like that, that is not what unions are for the language does not define that use case.  Second bitfields are very bad, never use them.  The compiler is going to do a shift and mask anyway unless the ISA has a bit set/clear instruction.  So use the shift and mask which is safe in C, and the compiler will optimize to bit set/clear if available otherwise it will shift and mask like it was going to anyway, but safely and reliably, and it is portable.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestion. I'm studying custom communication between 2 MCU via UART that can share value or control-flag. In order to let my code more clear to read and easily maintain by other people, I use this structure, but have no idea about the its safety in C, thanks again!

Comment: I second the bitfields being unsafe and not portable. `|=` and `&= ~` are idioms known to all embedded C programmers, hide them in a macro if you don't want to see them.

Answer (score 4):

C99 allows intializing members explicitly. Assuming I understand your question correctly, you're looking for

```
FLAG8 i = { .BIT = { .bit2 = 1, .bit5 = 1 } };
FLAG8 j = { .BYTE = 42 };
FLAG8 k = { 42 }; // same as j as initializing the first member is default
```

Comment: it's there a solution to do like FLAG8 i = 42 and manipulate bits like i.BIT.bit7 = 1?

Comment: @devilstan: by default, union initialization uses the first member (see edit); I believe that's the best you can do

Answer (score 2):

As normal you can assign like But the values are overlapped, because Here union holds only 1 byte of memory

```
FLAG8 i = { .BIT = { .bit2 = 1, .bit5 = 1 } , .BYTE = 42};
//result of i.BYTE is 42 depens on Byte value
FLAG8 i = {  .BYTE = 42 , .BIT = { .bit2 = 1, .bit5 = 1 } };
//result of i.BYTE is 36 depends on bits values
```

1.As @Christoph suggested You can assign value BYTE or bit by bit directly Like this

```
 FLAG8 i = { .BYTE = 42 };
 FLAG8 j = { .BIT = { .bit2 = 1, .bit5 = 1 } };
 printf("%d \n\n",(int)i.BYTE );
 printf("%d \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
```

2.You can assign value bit by bit

```
    i.BIT.bit0 = 1; // set bit0 of i.BYTE
    i.BIT.bit1 = 1;
    i.BIT.bit4 = 1;
   printf("%d \n\n",(int)i.BYTE );
```

3.You can assign directly a BYTE with hexa decimal value

```
  i.BYTE=0x10;
   printf("%d \n\n",(int)i.BYTE );
```

4.You can assign directly a BYTE with decimal value

```
i.BYTE=100;
printf("%d \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
```

5.You can assign directly with the Identifier of same type

```
j.BYTE=0x30;
printf("%d \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
i=j;
printf("%d \n\n",(int)i.BYTE );
```

6.Assign a decimal value and check it in printing both decimal and hexa decimal format

```
j.BYTE=100;
printf("%d \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
printf("%x \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
j.BIT.bit4=0;
j.BIT.bit5=0;
printf("%d \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
printf("%x \n\n",(int)j.BYTE );
```